# Why does my car have a knocking sound but i have oil in it?

Tags: engine

my car is over half way full of oil, but it has a knocking sound. I'm not sure if its from the oil or what but it knocks faster as I rev the engine or speed up. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Something inside the engine has been significantly damaged. Possibilities include a main bearing, a big-end conrod bearing. a small-end conrod bearing, piston ring or a piston it self. It's possible or likely that this damage occurred from running the motor low on oil, but the damage may well have occurred with a full supply of oil as well if oil pressure dropped for another cause. What kind of car? How old is it? How many miles?

Comment: Can you add a recording of the noise?

Comment: Before you assume the worst, rule out engine-driven accessories like water pump, alternator, power steering pump, A/C compressor, and even the idler/tensioner.  It _may_ be an internal engine problem but it may be something else.

Comment: jwh20, you forgot to tell him that it's possible to check those possibilities by removing the drive belts and running the engine briefly, if no noise it's one of those.  it's also possible that the catalytic converter has been melted down into a brick that rattles around as the exhaust blows on it. You can check by giving the converter a good whack with a rubber mallet, if there's a brick in it it'll rattle then too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some YouTube videos from searching YouTube:
diagnose engine knocking sound

https://youtu.be/BgmsA6nCV0o

https://youtu.be/JIOdS7XbHys

Is your check engine light on? Check for codes